# To read the index number on next page to display the DETAILS of the ARRAY

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, location-href

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <h1>Update User Information</h1>
                <div data-ng-controller="user">
                    <div data-ng-controller="userInfo">
                        <user-details user="users" user-filter="Single"></user-details>
    <user-details user="users" user-filter="Married"></user-details>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

**CONTROLLER + DIRECTIVE:**

.directive('userDetails', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          users: '=',
userFilter: '@'
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
          $scope.showEdit = function () {
            $scope.isEdit = true;
          }
        },
        template: `<div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Relation</th>
                  <th>Percentage</th>
                  <th></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users | filter: user.personalInfo.martialStatus= userFilter">
                  <td>{{user.personalInfo.firstName}} {{user.personalInfo.lastName}}</td>
                  <td>{{user.userRelations.relationshipType}}</td>
                  <td><span ng-if="!isEdit">{{user.personalInfo.percent}}</span><input type="text"
                          ng-if="isEdit" ng-model="user.personalInfo.percent" class="form-control"></td>
                  <td><a ng-click="showEdit()" href="#edit-user?index={{users.indexOf(user)}}">Update</a></td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
              <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">Total Percentage</td>
                  <td>100%</td>
                  <td><a ng-if="!isEdit" ng-click="showEdit()" href="#">Update</a><a ng-if="isEdit" ng-click="showEdit()" href="#">Save Percentage</a></td>
              </tr>
          </tfoot>
      </table>
  </div>`
      };
    })
```

Redirection new page HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <h1>EDIT User Information</h1>
            <div data-ng-controller="user">
                <div data-ng-controller="userInfo">
                   <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" data-ng-model="matt"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Help/guidance to -- how to retrieve the ARRAY index from url to next page to display the data to edit?

while redirection page, i'm able to pass the correct index like "#edit-user?index=1", but to iterate to get the index number in next page or need to do it controller?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you use `ui-route` or `ngRoute`?

Comment: ngRoute , ngRoute

Comment: If so, please post `$routeProvider` logic

Comment: `code`
      $scope.getUserDetails = function () {
        console.log('edittttttt bene', $location.search().beneIndex);
        $scope.userDetails = $scope.users[$location.search().beneIndex]; //HERE I'm not getting the $scope.users list on redirected page
      };
    }])`code`